# Validar duplicados en un campo con pydantic

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con pydantic y tengo la siguiente consulta:
Conocen alguna forma de validar que no haya valores duplicados dentro de una columna?

Me explico:

Actualmente tengo una clase con la que valido un json

```
class Schemafield(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: str
    mode: str
```

Dsp hago varias validaciones por ejemplo que el valor que llega en name no tenga mas de 300 caracteres:

```
@validator("name")
def column_name_is_long(cls, value):
    if len(value) > 300:
        raise ValueError("The column name may have up to 300 characters")
    return value
```

O por ejemplo que el valor de una columna solo acepte caracteres validos:

```
valid_characters = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"

@validator("name")
def column_name_valid_characters(cls, value):
    if re.search(valid_characters, value) is None:
        raise ValueError("Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or underscores (_)")
    return value
```

y final creo otra clase y le paso los fields

```
class SchemaFields(BaseModel):
    fields: List[Schemafield]
```

Este seria un ejemplo de un json que uso para testear:

```
{ "fields": [ {"name": "campo1", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo2", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo3", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo4", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo5", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo6", "type": "int", "mode": "null"} ] }
```

Ahora vuelvo a la consulta.
Me podrían guiar para poder armar una validación que reciba todos los valores del campo name y al final valide si hay alguno repetido? Por ejemplo si me llegan 2 campo1 seria error.

Hice varias prueba, por ejemplo ir guardando los valores en una lista y comparando si ya existen ahí, etc, pero no doy con la solución.

Aplique esta solución que plantean en esta consulta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003987/pydantic-checking-if-list-field-is-unique y funciono pero a medias: Sí me valida los name, pero si hay varios errores por ejemplo nombres de columna repetidos y otros de formato, la api solo me retorna el error de los nombres de columnas y ademas rompe otra validación propia de pydantic que es la que valida los nombres de las columnas que se declararon en la clase, si modifico el json y en alguno de los valores a type lo cambio a types funciona ok, mode si lo cambio a modes funciona ok pero name si lo cambio a names devuelve error 500

```
name: str
type: str
mode: str
```

Comment: Hola UserTest, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías [edit] y mostrar el **código** que has probado, como ejemplo de lo que estás explicando. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y que visites [ask] para aprender a realizar un [example]. Recibirás más respuestas, y de calidad, si la pregunta está correctamente redactada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si es esto lo que buscas, pero creo que el problema tiene fácil solución si metes un validador en la clase `SchemaFields`, en lugar de intentar hacerlo en la clase `Schemafield`.

Por ejemplo así:

```py
class SchemaFields(BaseModel):
    fields: List[Schemafield]

    @validator("fields")
    def names_must_be_unique(cls, value):
      fields = value
      if len(fields) != len(set(f.name for f in fields)):
        raise ValueError("The column name contains repeated names")
      return fields
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
ej = { "fields": [ {"name": "campo1", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo2", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo3", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo4", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo5", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo6", "type": "int", "mode": "null"} ] }

SchemaFields.validate(ej)  # Pasa ok

# Ahora modifico el ejemplo para que tenga un nombre repetido
ej["fields"][0]["name"] = "campo6"

# Y ya no pasa la validación
SchemaFields.validate(ej)

---------------------
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SchemaFields
fields
  The column name contains repeated names (type=value_error)
```

### Actualización

La misma idea de antes, pero con un validador que mola un poco más porque reporta además los nombres repetidos:

```py
from collections import Counter

class SchemaFields(BaseModel):
    fields: List[Schemafield]

    @validator("fields")
    def names_must_be_unique(cls, value):
      fields = value
      count = Counter(f.name for f in fields)
      repeats = ", ".join(item for item, c in count.items() if c>1)
      if repeats:
        raise ValueError(f"Repeated names in column name: ({repeats})")
      return fields
```

Ejemplo:

```
ej = { "fields": [ {"name": "campo1", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo2", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo3", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo4", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo5", "type": "int", "mode": "null"}, 
{"name": "campo6", "type": "int", "mode": "null"} ] }

SchemaFields.validate(ej)  # Pasa ok

# Ahora modifico el ejemplo para que tenga dos nombres repetidos
ej["fields"][0]["name"] = "campo6"
ej["fields"][1]["name"] = "campo5"

# Y ya no pasa la validación
SchemaFields.validate(ej)
```

---

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SchemaFields
fields
  Repeated names in column name: (campo6, campo5) (type=value_error)
```

Comment: Esa ultima funcion me salvo el día, muchas gracias!